# Determine coordinates $x_c$ and $y_c$

Tags: physics

[image]

**Answer: $x_c=18.2$ and $y_c=9.5$.**

Who can solve with explanation?

Comment: so it means that  $x_c$ and $y_c$ are coordinates of  center of small circle?

Comment: no it means Area of triangle+Area of rectangle-Area of circle with own midlle poiont of each other

Answer (score 1):

Given the distributive property of the centroid, calling $A_i, i=1,2,3$ the areas of the triangle, rectangle and circle, respectively, and $P_i=(x_i,y_i)$ the respective centroids, we have

\begin{align}
x_c&=\frac{A_1x_1+A_2x_2-A_3x_3}{A_1+A_2-A_3}\\
   &=\frac{a^2\cdot\frac{2}{3}a+4a^2\cdot2a-\pi r^2\cdot2a}{a^2+4a^2-\pi r^2}
\end{align}

and similarly for $y_c$

\begin{align}
y_c&=\frac{A_1y_1+A_2y_2-A_3y_3}{A_1+A_2-A_3}\\
   &=\frac{a^2\cdot\frac{2}{3}a+4a^2\cdot a-\pi r^2\cdot a}{a^2+4a^2-\pi r^2}
\end{align}

given the centroid of the triangle $(2a/3, 2a/3)$ and the common centroid of the rectangle and of the circle $(2a,a)$.

Comment: for case of $y_c$,if the same values  would be,then what is  difference?

Comment: @datodatuashvili: the difference is that you use $y_1, y_2, y_3$

Comment: and first one will be,i mean numerator,could you update please full answer

Comment: could you tell me please where does $2a/3$ and $a/3$ comes from?

Comment: @datodatuashvili: are the coordinates $x_1, y_1$ of the centroid of the triangle, given by a known formula as the arithmetic mean value of the coordinates of the vertices $(x_a+x_b+x_c)/3$, $(y_a+y_b+y_c)/3$

Comment: yes but we should have three coordinate yes?for rectanguar and circle the same?we dont know coordinate of center of circle

Comment: @datodatuashvili: center of rectangle and circle from the figure are the same and equal to $(2a,a)$

Comment: one of my friend is interested -while taking the y of the triangle, why didn't you take 2a/3, as the side of triangle is 2a not a

Comment: @datodatuashvili: this is correct, because $x_1=(0+a+a)/3$, but I was wrong with $y_1=(0+0+2a)/3=2a/3$ and not $a/3$ as I did above. I'm going to edit the post.

Comment: while finding Triangle's  Y, why did you take a/3 as the side of the triangle is 2a and you should have taken 2a/3

Comment: if you solve by using this formulas, you can't get the answer.

Comment: @AnzorBukhrashvili: I already found the mistake about $y_2$, for the rest I see that my solution leads to 16.8364 and 9.2091, but I cannot say why this does not correspond the the expected answer.